# Yii-like GridView for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, yii

I've been using Yii for a long time but now I want to have some stuff with Ruby on Rails. I always loved Yii [GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) because I could easily display my record from the database with filters and pagination. I wonder but it had AJAX support.
Do you know some gems which provide such functional with AJAX filtering and pagination? I found [datagrid](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid). But it has no AJAX support.

Comment: There's probably a [jQuery plugin](https://jqueryui.com/) that handles this.

Comment: @tadman It works on client's side, isn't it? I need something that will get data from server in each request(filtering, sorting, etc)

Comment: Some are client-side only, others can automatically fetch on demand. It depends on what you need.

Comment: I need some kind of [this](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid) but this AJAX. I don't want to load all data at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://datatables.net/
is a jQuery plugin that can add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table.

https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails

and

https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails

are two gems that integrate DataTables with Rails

Answer (score 0):

There are several gems that may be helpful in a more general sense if you go away from Ajax:

- https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari
- https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

But for strict ajax support you might use something like

- https://github.com/ronalchn/ajax_pagination

Comment: These gems are paginators. The general problem isn't in paginator. It's in the gem which represents datagrid